# How do I change the widget type of the DELETE field in a django formset

Tags: python, django

I'm using a formset with can_delete=True. I want to change the widget of the DELETE field to a hidden input. I can't seem to find a good way to do this. What I've tried is:

Change the form's widget to HiddenInput and/or add a hidden field in the form definition:

```
class MyForm(ModelForm):
    DELETE = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        widgets = {'DELETE' : forms.HiddenInput}
```

Do the above with a change in the formset

```
class MyFormSet(BaseModelFormSet):

def add_fields(self, form, index):
    originalDeletion = None
    if DELETION_FIELD_NAME in form.fields:
        originalDeletion = form.fields[DELETION_FIELD_NAME]

    super(MyFormSet, self).add_fields(form,index)

    if originalDeletion is not None:
        form.fields[DELETION_FIELD_NAME] = originalDeletion
```

If I do these both it does actually change the field to hidden but this seems like a bit of a hack (effectively overwriting the usual add_fields method). How are you supposed to do this?

== EDIT ==

It turns out that using a hidden field is not so good with the form framework anyway. You should definitely use a checkbox and hide it with css. If you want to do adjust the css of the checkbox in Django I still think you have to change the add_fields method as above, which then allows you to change the widget's css.

Comment: Why does it **has** to be of type=hidden ? Aren't the other ways of hiding it good too ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It doesn't change anything if your input is of type=hidden, or if it is of type=checkbox **and** display: none.

IMHO the elegant way in CSS would look like this:

```
td.delete input { display: none; }
```

Or in JavaScript:

```
$('td.delete input[type=checkbox]').hide()
```

Or, in the admin:

```
django.jQuery('td.delete input[type=checkbox]').hide()
```

That seems like a better direction to take because:

1. It **won't change your JavaScript code** and
2. It's **one line of code** vs. so much Python hacks

Comment: Ah - so you hide it in the javascript / css. That makes sense. Still seems strange there is no way to do this directly in django - I guess the equivalent would be to add a css class to the widget which hides it. Doesn't seem like you can do that though because it doesn't let you override the DELETE widget.

Answer (score 27):

The shortest code to accomplish what you need is:

```
class MyFormSet(BaseFormSet):
    def add_fields(self, form, index):
        super(MyFormSet, self).add_fields(form, index)
        form.fields[DELETION_FIELD_NAME].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
```

It cannot be considered a hack because it's mentioned in the official Django docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/formsets/#adding-additional-fields-to-a-formset

Django sources to read:

- [definition of DELETION_FIELD_NAME](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.4.1/django/forms/formsets.py#L20)
- [definition of add_fields() method](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.4.1/django/forms/formsets.py#L312)
- [the place in which add_field() is called - after a form is constructed, so you cannot do anything in Form.**_*init*_**()](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.4.1/django/forms/formsets.py#L134)

Comment: The link is now 404. This is a new which hopefully won't 404 any time soon: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#adding-additional-fields-to-a-formset

Answer (score 1):

Setting `self.can_delete` to `False` solved my problem:

```
class MyFormSet(BaseFormSet): 
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        super(MyFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 
        self.can_delete = False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also override the initializer in the FORMSET (NOT FORMS) class, because the `DELETE` field is created by the `Formset`.

```
class YourFormSet(BaseFormSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for form in self.forms:
            form.fields["DELETE"].widget = YourWidget()
```

Answer (score 0):

Django's `BaseFormSet` defines a `delete_widget` attribute that can be overridden in a subclass:

```py
from django.forms.formsets import BaseFormSet, BaseInlineFormSet
from django.forms.widgets import HiddenInput, CheckboxInput

class CustomFormSet(BaseFormSet):
    delete_widget = HiddenInput

class CustomCheckboxInput(CheckboxInput):
    template_name = "my/custom/checkbox.html"

class CustomInlineFormset(BaseInlineFormSet):
    delete_widget = CustomCheckboxInput
```

If the details of the DELETE field need to be modified, such as the label, or type of field, then `BaseFormSet.add_fields` can be extended or overridden:

```py
from django.forms.formsets import BaseFormSet, DELETION_FIELD_NAME
from django.forms.fields import BooleanField

class CustomBooleanField(BooleanField):
    # ...

class CustomFormSet(BaseFormSet):
    def add_fields(self, form, index):
        super().add_fields(form, index)

        if form.fields.get(DELETION_FIELD_NAME, None) is not None:
            form.fields[DELETION_FIELD_NAME] = CustomBooleanField(
                # ...
            )
```