# Django - Modify Inlineformset Delete button

Tags: django, django-forms, inline-formset

I do a custom UI/UX for an inlineformset.

By default the inlineformset widget has a delete button.

I wan to add and remove forms from inlineformset dynamic using javascript.
In some cases the delete is just a button instead of the checkbox, in other cases is in a modal window.

When a user click delete the form is removed from the page with javascript.

So, I try to do this without using the default widget, render fields in the template, but I don't know how to tell Django witch fields to remove and if is necessary to readjust the ids and names of the fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution for this problem was to just overwrite the template_name of CheckboxInput widget class:

```
widgets.CheckboxInput.template_name = 'widgets/delete.html'
```

I added that in my {app}/widgets.py that hosts my custom widgets. As I am using the same format accross my app, I think it's the only way to go.

{app}/templates/widgets/delete.html:

```
<div class="checkbox checkbox-styled">
<label>
    <input name={{ widget.name }} type="checkbox" value="true" {% if widget.attrs.checked == True %}checked{% endif %}>
    <span>Delete</span>
</label>
</div>
```

**If it would not have been** the **inlineformset_factory** then the best way was to create a new class extending BaseFormSet and to overwrite the widget in **add_fields** method like suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12798786/1957846).