# Reorder DELETE Field in Formset

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a Django formset that is displayed as a table with one form per table. I would like to add a checkbox in the first column of the table so that the user to check it if they would like to delete the row (form).

I have the javascript to manage the deletion of the formset row (form) and modify the management form on the front end, but I am having an issue when I add the DELETE field to the form. I used the solution reference in [modify DELETE widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379512/how-do-i-change-the-widget-type-of-the-delete-field-in-a-django-formset) so that I could add the class "delete" to all of my delete fields for use in CSS and JS on the front end. When the DELETE field is added it is always the last field in the form. I would like it to be first.

**models.py**

```
class ModelOne(models.Model):
    attr_one = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    attr_two = models.CharField(max_length=16)
```

**forms.py**

```
class BaseFormOneFormset(BaseModelFormSet):
    def add_fields(self, form, index) -> None:
        super().add_fields(form, index)
        form.fields[DELETION_FIELD_NAME].widget = forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class':"delete"})
        form.fields["id"].widget=forms.HiddenInput(attrs={'class':'pk'}) 

class FormOne(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelOne

    attr_one = forms.CharField(max_length=16,
                               required=True,
                               label="attr_one",
                               widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':5,'class':'required '}))
    attr_two = forms.CharField(max_length=16,
                               required=True,
                               label="attr_two",
                               widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':5,'class':'required '}))
```

**views.py**

```
def view_one(request):
    formset_factory_one = modelformset_factory( ModelOne,
                                                FormOne,
                                                formset=BaseFormOneFormset,
                                                extra=0,
                                                can_delete=True)
    formset_one = formset_factory_one(query_set=FormOne.objects.all(),
                                      prefix="formone")
    return render(request, "app_one/template_one.html",{"formset_one":formset_one})
```

**template_one.html**

```
<table id="tbl-id">
    <thead id="tbl-head-id">
        <tr>
            {% for form in formset_one|slice:":1" %}
                {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                    <th>{{field.label|safe}}</th>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
        </tr> 
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbl-body-id">
        {% for form in formset_one %}
            <tr id="row{{forloop.counter0}}-id" class="formset-row">
                {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                    <td>
                        {{field}}
                    </td>
                {% endfor %}
                {% for field in form.hidden_fields %}
                    <td hidden >{{field}}</td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Resulting Table**

[image of resulting html table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pU6Ig.png)

**Solutions tried**

I have already tried to set the [Form.field_order](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/api/#notes-on-field-ordering) both in the `FormOne` class declaration

```
class FormOne(forms.ModelForm):
    field_order = [ DELETION_FIELD_NAME, "attr_one", "attr_two"]
```

and in the `BaseFormset.add_fields` method

```
def add_fields(self, form, index) -> None:
    super().add_fields(form, index)
    form.fields[DELETION_FIELD_NAME].widget = forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class':"delete"})
    form.fields["id"].widget=forms.HiddenInput(attrs={'class':'pk'})
    form.field_order = [ DELETION_FIELD_NAME, "attr_one", "attr_two"]
```

These both result in the DELETE field still last in the order.

Answer (score 0):

Although there are ways to change the order of the DELETE field by overriding the formset's add_fields() function, it is pretty tedious and kinda complicated.

However, if your goal is to simply render DELETE first, or in a completely different part of the page, you are in luck. This is easily accomplished in the template.

The delete field can be rendered explicitly in the template using `{{ form.DELETE }}` which is equivalent to the regular output of `{{ field }}` that you get when iterating through `form.fields`.

**Simple example to render DELETE field first:**

```
{# this renders the DELETE field #}
{{ form.DELETE }} 

{# now render the other fields #}
{% for field in form.visible_fields %} 
  {# if check to prevent DELETE rendering twice #}
  {% if field.name != 'DELETE' %}  
    {{ field }}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

**Applied to the code from your question:**

```
<table id="tbl-id">
    <thead id="tbl-head-id">
        <tr>
            {% for form in formset_one|slice:":1" %}
                {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                    <th>Delete</th>
                    {% if field.name !='DELETE' %}
                    <th>{{field.label|safe}}</th>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
        </tr> 
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbl-body-id">
        {% for form in formset_one %}
            <tr id="row{{forloop.counter0}}-id" class="formset-row">
                    <td>
                        {{ form.DELETE }}
                    </td>
                {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                    {% if field.name != 'DELETE' %}
                    <td>
                        {{field}}
                    </td>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
                {% for field in form.hidden_fields %}
                    <td hidden >{{field}}</td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```